# JQuery Load() syntax - Changing data source on mouseenter

Tags: jquery

Hey everyone.  I've written this simple function that is supposed to load a portion of an XML file on mouseenter.  It works fine when I specify the data source explicitly, shown below.

I have a number of '.invest-port-thumb' divs, each with a unique link.

The following code works fine—but it loads the whole XML file—and I only want a portion:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.invest-port-thumb a').mouseenter(function() {
            $('#slider-name').load(this.href);
        });
    });
```

This code also works fine—loading only the 'cName' portion that I want it to load...Except that this code refers to one of the files, instead of the value of `this.href`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.invest-port-thumb a').mouseenter(function() {
            $('#slider-name').load('port/atd.xml cName');
        });
    });
```

I guess what I'm saying, syntax wise—How can I combine `this.href` and the data matching `cName`?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#slider-name').load(this.href + ' cName'); // watch out for the space...
```

Comment: This works fine. Thanks Reigel! I forgot that space before cName!!

Comment: While I'm at it--How can I refer to an XML attribute in this situation? 'cName' is an element node, and 'cind' is an attribute of cName.  I'd like to display 'cind' elsewhere..